# Convert Image format in android java

Tags: java, android, graphics, image-manipulation, eclipse-adt

How do i ***convert Image format*** from within my android application activity.

I have the code to *convert image format using Java*, but it doesn't output the image with good quality and also similar code is not working in Android's Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't post any of your code, so i have no idea what is wrong with your code. but you can convert a image to PNG or JPEG like this:

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); //100-best quality
   out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: A bitmap of your image (input)

Comment: And what about Gif and animated webp which has multiple frames

Answer (score 0):

For example, from Bitmap to JPG:

```
Bitmap bmp;
JPEG_QUALITY = 80;
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, JPEG_QUALITY, out);
```

Comment: from Bitmap to JPG? what is a Bitmap den? another format? I want to convert from PNG to JPG or vice versa.

Comment: **here is my code in android, but where do i put my original image url** 'public class Main extends Activity
{
 Bitmap bmp;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  try{
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jjj.jpg");
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,out);
   out.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}'

Comment: It depends on which image are you pretending to convert? do you have it in your phone, do you receive it through internet... ?

Comment: You can use Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourPath);

Comment: so BitmapFactory.decode() will initialize my Bitmap object to the image, is it correct?